# Is it possible to pass the foreign key id in Django rest-framework URL?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using routers in Django Rest Framework and trying to create a dynamic URL based on a foreign key. My `urls.py` file looks like this,

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('user/<int:user_id>/profile', ProfileViewSet, 'profile')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

My `models.py` file looks like below,

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='profile_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    character = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

My `views.py` file looks like below,

```py
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

I am getting the 404 error in all (post, put, get) request. Is there any possible easy solution for such kind of implementation?

**Edit**

This is my resulting URL (GET request):

```
http:localhost:8000/user/1/profile
```

And I am getting the following result:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/user/1/profile
```

Comment: `'user/<user_id>/profile'` did you try this? I guess `user_id` is the pk in your case?

Comment: Yes, `user_id` is my primary key. I tried with your suggestion, but still `404 error`.

Comment: Can you post the resulting url plz. And what is `IntensityClassViewSet`?

Comment: have you tried puting `lookup_field = 'user_id'` inside `ProfileViewSet`?

Comment: Hi @Jonas, I just added the resulting URL. Sorry, `IntensityClassViewSet` means `ProfileViewSet`. I just corrected my question.

Comment: Hi @Adil, I have tried with `lookup_field` too, it is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the URL in regex format, my issue was solved. Instead of this,

```py
router.register('user/<int:user_id>/profile', ProfileViewSet, 'profile')
```

I wrote this,

```py
router.register(r'user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/profile', ProfileViewSet, 'profile')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
router.register('user/<int:user_id>/profile', ProfileViewSet, 'intensity_classes')
```

Use this

```
router.register(r'users', ProfileViewSet, basename='user')
```

Then for list view

http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/ -> List of profiles

For detail view

http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/13
->here `13` is the profile id, you can **update**, **delete** the Profile instance

Comment: I need to implement this kind of URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/{user_id}/profile/{profile_id}`. Is there any possible way? The main reason behind this kind of URL is, one user can have multiple profiles.

Comment: oh, now I see! you need to serialize the User model, not the Profile, then using `SerializerMethodField` you can design a nested serializer with corresponding profile objects. Share your `User` model if you're using a custom User model